# Тонкости подключения новой Apache Poi 5.0.0

Tags: java, gradle, apache-poi, android-gradle

Так как совсем недавно выпустилась Apache Poi 5.0.0, обязательно ли подключать multidex? Мне от Apache Poi нужно только чтение Excel .xls и xlsx, может есть вариант также подключать не целую Apache Poi, а только часть? Сейчас стоит gradle:4.1.2

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi ?